# Confirm I understand matrix determinants

Tags: matrix, 3d, determinants

Basically I have been **trying** to forge an understanding of matrix maths over the last few weeks and after reading (and re-reading) many maths heavy articles and documentation I *think* I have an adequate understanding, but I just wanted to make sure!

The definitions i have ended up with are:

```
/*
    Minor
    -----
    -A determinant of a sub matrix
    -The sub matrix used to calculate a minor can be obtained by removing more then one row/column from the original matrix
    -First minors are minors of a sub matrix where only the row and column of a single element have been removed

    Cofactor
    --------
    -The (signed) minor of a single element from a matrix
     ie. the minor of element 2,3 is the determinant of the submatrix, of the matrix, defined by removing row 2 and column 3

    Determinant
    -----------
    -1. Choose any single row or column from a Matrix.
     2. For each element in the row/column, multiply the value of the element against the First Minor of that element.
     3. This result is then multiplied by (-1 raised to the power of the elements row index + its column index) which will give the result of step 2 a sign.
     4. You then simply sum all these results to get the determinant (a real number) for the Matrix.
*/
```

Please let me know of any holes in my understanding?

**Sources**
http://en.wikipedia.org /Cofactor_(linear_algebra) & /Minor_(linear_algebra) & /Determinant
http://easyweb.easynet.co.uk/~mrmeanie/matrix/matrices.htm
http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LaplaceExpansionTheorem.pdf  (the most helpful)
[Geometric tools for computer graphics](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=82kntxqd1BoC&dq=schneider+geometric+tools&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=4sWDSvP_A5qRjAeO5t2JCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#v=onepage&q=&f=false) (this may have missing pages, i have the full copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you understand determinants -- now go forth and write code!  Try writing a solver for simultaneous linear equations in 3 or more variables, using Cramer's Rule.

Since you tagged this question 3dgraphics, matrix and vector multiplication might be a good area to explore next.  They come up everywhere in 3d graphics programming.